# find the geometric probability

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

A straight line of length $10cm$ is divided into $3$ parts by $2$ points taken at random, the chance that no part is greater than $6 $is?

my approach : $10 cm $of length is divided into $3$ segments. Let two of the segments be $x$ and $y$ and 3rd $10-x-y$ and $x$ lies between $0$ and $10$ and so does y. Therefore total area from which i can choose points $x$ and $y$(which will give the segments) will be $100$. Now imposing given conditions  by appropriate inequalities gives a answer. Is the method correct?

Answer (score 3):

[image]
If we put the length of each segment on the coordinate axes, then the set of possible division is distributed across the blue green plane, $ x+y+z = 10$ with the green areas representing the possibilities that one segment is greater than $6$

Find the area of the green bits proportional to the area entire triangle.

Comment: Those are tetrahedrons right?

Comment: They are triangles on the plane $x+y+z = 10$ where $x\ge 6$ or $y\ge 6$ or $z\ge 6$

Comment: yeah which ultimately means tetrahedrons.

Comment: No, triangles.  All of the possibilities project onto a plane.

Comment: i cannot get you. Im sorry

Comment: And I thought I was so clever....Here is a more straightforward approach. $x_1, x_2$ are the points that divide the original segment, they are uniformly distributed across the interval $[0,10]$  find $P(x_1\land x_2) \ge 6 + P(x_1\land x_2) \le 4 + P(|x_2-x_1|) \ge 6$  each term corresponds to one of the green triangles in my figure.

Comment: @user354545 tetrahedrons are 3 dimensional figures meaning they have volumes. Those bits are triangles with 0 volume but do have a area